# jfilechooser - set directory to a path in a file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to set the directory path in JFilechooser through something like this(using commons-io ) :

```
String fileContents = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("path.txt"));
File theDirectory = new File(fileContents);

filechooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

I'm using getCanonicalPath() to get the path and write in the file path.txt

```
path = file.getCanonicalPath();
```

I don't intend to put all my code here,but I'm sure that the program writes and reads the path in path.txt.
I don't get any error,but everytime I run the program it always open JFilechooser in my documents folder.What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `theDirectory` and whether it exists? `System.out.println( theDirectory.getCanonicalPath() + " exists: " + theDirectory.exists() );` If the file no longer exists, then the file chooser will default to the My Documents folder.

Answer (score 22):

Try to pass the current directory directly in the constructor:

```
filechooser = new JFileChooser(theDirectory);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you consult the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), using the default constructor (i.e. `new JFileChooser()`):

> Constructs a JFileChooser pointing to
>   the user's default directory. This
>   default depends on the operating
>   system. It is typically the "My
>   Documents" folder on Windows, and the
>   user's home directory on Unix.

This would *seem* to account for always opening to *My Documents*, but this **isn't** your problem. In fact, your problem lies with **setting the current directory** (i.e. `setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory)`):

> Sets the current directory. Passing in
>   null sets the file chooser to point to
>   the user's default directory. This
>   default depends on the operating
>   system. It is typically the "My
>   Documents" folder on Windows, and the
>   user's home directory on Unix. **If the
>   file passed in as currentDirectory is
>   not a directory, the parent of the
>   file will be used as the
>   currentDirectory. If the parent is not
>   traversable, then it will walk up the
>   parent tree until it finds a
>   traversable directory, or hits the
>   root of the file system.**

That being said, I'd pay attention to the **highlighted text** since it appears that you're setting a *file* as the current directory and not a *directory*.

Comment: I'm not setting a file as the current directory.I'm trying to set the current directory with the last directory selected                   File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();                        What i'm tryng to do is always open filechooser with the last directory selected even if i close the program and run it again

Comment: @fermk090: then you're going to have to persist the `last directory selected` and when you run the program again, load the persisted directory.

Comment: I think that is what he is doing. He's persistinting the location into 'path.txt' and recovering it.

Answer (score 1):

In your main class declare

```
public static String dirpath=".";

private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
 JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(dirpath);
 dirpath =jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For select the last directory that you open :

```
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(lastDirectory);

int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());

if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
   lastDirectory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JFileChooser Chooser = new JFileChooser("F:");

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the directory theb use System.getProperty method

```
String s=System.getProperty("user.dir");  // changes directory from documents to the user current Directory;
```

JFileChooser jfc=new JFileChooser(s);