# Prepopulating file name in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I pretty much want to do this:

[Save using JFileChooser with pre-populated file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401285/save-using-jfilechooser-with-pre-populated-file-name)

Goal is to have, upon initializing the dialog, predefined name in the File name (Direcory name, acctually) textbox.

However, I want only directories to be displayed: `.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY)`

With that, the code provided in the question doesn't work.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jfilechooser-set-directory-to-a-path-in-a-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721504/jfilechooser-set-directory-to-a-path-in-a-file)

Comment: Nope, it's not, we're trying different things here...

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721504/jfilechooser-set-directory-to-a-path-in-a-file pass the directory name in the JFileChooser constructor.